# evaluating many functions at a single point using map

Tags: dictionary, vectorization, elm

I was able to make a nice picture with Elm's [share-elm.com](http://share-elm.com/sprout/53d6e5bfe4b07afa6f9837ed) any tips for code optimization would be appreciated but I am focusing on the last two lines:

```elm
xflip : (number, number) -> (number, number)
xflip pt = ( -1*(fst pt), snd pt)

rot : (number, number) -> (number, number)
rot pt = ( -1*(snd pt), fst pt)

mul : number -> (number, number) -> (number, number)
mul a b = (a*(fst b), a*(snd b))

add : (number, number) -> (number, number) -> (number, number)
add a b = ((fst a)+(fst b), (snd a)+(snd b))

-- implementations of the symmetries of hilbert space curve

t1 : (number, number) -> (number, number)
t1 b = (add (mul 0.5 (-100,-100)) ((mul 0.5) (rot (rot(rot (xflip b))) )))

t2 : (number, number) -> (number, number)
t2 b = (add (mul 0.5 (-100,100)) ((mul 0.5) (b)))

t3 : (number, number) -> (number, number)
t3 b = (add (mul 0.5 (100,100)) ((mul 0.5) ( b)))

t4 : (number, number) -> (number, number)
t4 b = (add (mul 0.5 (100,-100)) ((mul 0.5) (rot (xflip b) )))

--

t : [(number, number)] -> [(number, number)]
t z = (map t1 z) ++ (map t2 z) ++ (map t3 z) ++ (map t4 z)
```

I don't know if this is the best say to define vector addition or 2D transformations, but I needed to do it somehow.  Often done with [vector graphics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_graphics) on the graphics themselves, I am working with list of points before they become `Path` types.

Was this the best way to iterate the rotation function `rot` ?  I needed to rotate 90 degrees left and then right.  So I rotated left 3 times:

```elm
rot (rot(rot (xflip b)))
```

Onto the main question, could my last two lines be streamlined:

```
t : [(number, number)] -> [(number, number)]
t z = (map t1 z) ++ (map t2 z) ++ (map t3 z) ++ (map t4 z)
```

The list of numbers are will become my `Path` objects and `t1` through `t4` are functions.  I thought maybe I could iterate over these functions with `map`.  It works in the cases I tried on Github gist: https://gist.github.com/MonsieurCactus/ef285584f1588289b477  Here's what I tried:

```elm
t : [(number, number)] -> [(number, number)]
t z = map ( \f -> (map f z)) [t1, t2, t3 ,t4]
```

The Elm compiler returned the error message:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main                ( Main.elm )
Type error on line 49, column 7 to 46:
        map (\f -> map f z) [t1,t2,t3,t4]

   Expected Type: (Float)
     Actual Type: _List

Type error on line 49, column 7 to 46:
        map (\f -> map f z) [t1,t2,t3,t4]

   Expected Type: Float
     Actual Type: (Float, Float)
```

Maybe I should have tried writing a function `[Path] -> [Path]` but then I have to get the list of points and change them anyway.

Answer (score 1):

## Streamlining the last two lines

Your attempt at shortening the definition of `t` is in the right direction. But because you map over the list of functions (`[t1,t2,t3,t4]`), and inside the mapping function you map over the list of points `z`, you end up with a list of lists of points (`[[(number,number)]]` instead of `[(number, number)]`).
So you still need to [`concat`](http://library.elm-lang.org/catalog/evancz-Elm/0.12/List#concat) that list of lists. You can also use [`concatMap`](http://library.elm-lang.org/catalog/evancz-Elm/0.12/List#concatMap) instead of a loose `concat` and `map`:

```
t : [(number, number)] -> [(number, number)]
t z = concatMap ( \f -> (map f z)) [t1, t2, t3 ,t4]
```

## Iterating `rot`

If you don't mind using `Float` everywhere instead of `number`, you can change your `rot` function to take a rotation to perform. Using some [basic functions](http://library.elm-lang.org/catalog/evancz-Elm/0.12/Basics#angle-conversions), you could write something like:

```
rot' : Float -> (Float, Float) -> (Float, Float)
rot' angle point = 
    let (r,th) = toPolar point
        th' = th + angle
    in fromPolar (r,th')

rot = rot' (degrees 90)
```